# Q promises in Node js v/s Call back

Tags: node.js, promise

I need to understand one point in the Q promise OR any other Node module where async calls are handled.When we have a function calling a call back  then will that call back is handled before next function in the async chain assuming we are calling series of Functions ?

Comment: Showing us the code you don't understand would help. What specifically do you mean by "async chain"? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling multiple functions in parallel then all function executes simultaneously and the whole process ends when every function has called their respective callbacks in any order. Whereas if you call functions in series, next function executes only after the previous one has called its callback.